# Android Studio Error on Data Binding after upgrading to Studio 4.2 Canary 5

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using data binding to inflate the view of a fragment. It was working fine before I upgraded Android Studio to version 4.2 Canary 5. It also asked me to upgrade the `gradle` version to `4.2.0-alpha05` which upgraded the default language feature to `Java 8`. But now the data binding section is throwing a `NullPointerException`. I want some help here. Below is the trace of the error.

```
2020-07-22 01:11:13.437 18307-18307/com.deamat.mydeamat.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.deamat.mydeamat.debug, PID: 18307
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deamat.mydeamat.debug/com.deamat.mydeamat.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentSignupBinding.in…          false
            ) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentSignupBinding.in…          false
            ) must not be null
        at com.deamat.auth.SignupFragment.onCreateView(SignupFragment.kt:27)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6959)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890)
            ... 9 more
```

Here is the data binding call

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
       val binding = FragmentSignupBinding.inflate(
            inflater,
            container,
            false
        )

        ...
}
```

Note: I am using multiple modules in my app and I have enabled data binding inside each module. However the login_fragment layout is within the same module as the Fragment class.

Comment: Post your fragment and Main activty onCreateView method code

Comment: @chandmohd it's at the bottom. the variable `binding` is already null when I debug. And that's the first line. Everything below it throws NullPointerException.

Comment: @MerhawiFissehaye the stacktrace indicates FragmentSignUp but the code snippet showing the fragment's `onCreateView` is referring to the FragmentLogin. Could you post the FragmentSignUp's `onCreateView` instead?

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár ya. Sorry done.

Comment: I've built an example app but couldn't reproduce the error you're facing. For me DataBinding works properly with AndroidStudio 4.2 Canary 5. If you haven't figured it out yet I'd be happy to help so please provide an example app where the aforementioned error happens.

Comment: Okay thank you for taking the time @ZsoltBoldizsár. Maybe another part of my code or configuration is causing the problem. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Databinding is broken for us too since updating to AS 4.2 Canary 5 / Gradle 4.2.0-alpha05. We can't even build our app.

In our case it seems to be related to custom BindingAdapter's. Removing their usage from layout files, the app can be build - though missing the corresponding logic. Not a solution really, so we had to downgrade to Canary 4 for now.

Comment: I have no custom binding adapters, so what I did for now is remove the data binding and do my views the old way. I had submitted an issue on Android issue tracker and they said it's working on a fresh install. So I suppose another part of my code is breaking the data binding. Thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: Regarding the binding adapter issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161940255 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161814391

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
class PracticeFragment:Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPracticeBinding//declare your binding 

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = PracticeFragment()
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentPracticeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    }
}
```